# Python: How can I read the elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning Python and have some problems now. I trying to get the letter frequency of a crypted text and want switch some letters. So far so good

```
import collections

file = open('chipertext.txt', 'r')
text = file.read()
print text
```

> lrvmnir bpr sumvbwvr jx bpr lmiwv yjeryrkbi jx qmbm wi
>   bpr xjvni mkd ymibrut jx irhx wi bpr riirkvr jx

```
letters = collections.Counter(text)
print letters
```

> Counter({' ': 18, 'r': 14, 'i': 10, 'b': 8, 'm': 7, 'j': 6, 'v': 6, 'x': 6, 'p': 4, 'w': 4, 'k': 3, 'y': 3, 'l': 2, 'n': 2, 'u': 2, '\n': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'q': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1})

I'm not sure how I have access to the elements of 'letters'. I like get the numbers of the letters like r = letter[2] and get the count 14

update:
Is there also a way to iterate trough the elements ? To get sometihing like:

```
  18
r 14
i 10
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a subclass of `dict`. Hence, you can access the elements of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) just like you would access elements of any normal dictionary. Example for the count of `'r'` , you can use - `letters['r']` . Example -

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter({' ': 18, 'r': 14, 'i': 10, 'b': 8, 'm': 7, 'j': 6, 'v': 6, 'x': 6, 'p': 4, 'w': 4, 'k': 3, 'y': 3, 'l': 2, 'n': 2, 'u': 2, '\n': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'q': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1})
>>> c['r']
14
```

---

For the new requirement in the question -

> update: Is there also a way to iterate trough the elements ?

Yes, you can iterate over it as you iterate over a normal dictionary. Example -

```
for key,count in letters.iteritems():
    print key, count
```

Comment: Just a note, you can simply think of `Counter` as a `dict` (for most cases).